# Is the any documentation on chronos-etu?

Tags: autodesk-forge

I am trying to integrate a time slider widget from [chronos-etu](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chronos-etu) to my app. Is there any documentation for it? what are the required inputs to create a new instance of time slider and such info.

My app is a vanilla JavaScript app.

I tried to add this src in my UI: `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chronos-etu@5.0.0/chronos-etu.min.js" type= "module"></script>`

and I get this erorr:`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Container') at Object.<anonymous> (chronos-etu.min.js:309)`

Comment: Let me ask the creators of the library.

Comment: @PetrBroz Hi Petr :) any news from the team?

Comment: Just heard from the creator of the component. There's no official documentation for the component as of now (it's mainly published to npm so that the reference application can use it) but the team is working on a series of blog posts that will help external developers make use of the component as well. I will post an answer to this question as soon as the first blog post is available.

Answer (score 0):

Hi @mahshid sorry for the extremely late response. As @Petr mentioned, this package is for the reference app, but as of 5.7.1 I've started exporting the docs along with the public package. Hopefully that helps.